# Complete passthrough of request to .net generic handler to another endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

This may initially sound like an odd request, but I want a generic .net handler (.ashx) that essentially takes everything sent to it (headers, posted data, query string params, etc, etc, etc) and passes it all along to a different endpoint that will be passed via a querystring parameter.  If I can have the endpoint QS param removed, that would be a bonus, but probably not essential.

I have a couple of APIs that I call (external ones that I have no control over) that I can call from one server, but not from my dev machine.

I want to be able to change the endpoints in my web.config file from:

```
http://somedomain.com/api/getData.dll
```

to

```
http://example.com/myHandler.ashx?endpoint=somedomain.com%2Fapi%2FgetData.dll
```

Then my handler would take anything sent to it, send it along to the urldecoded version of the "endpoint" QS param, and return all data to the original calling system with the correct content-type, etc.

Sounds pointless and a little crazy to me, but necessary in my case for dev testing only.

Since it's only dev testing, speed isn't really all that important, since staging and production systems can hit the API directly.

Am I asking something that's simple?

Thanks

Comment: You could set up an [HTTP proxy](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on your server and pass your traffic through that.  Essentially the same thing you are doing except you don't have to write the proxy code.

Comment: I don't have access to setup a proxy on the server.  I was hoping that it would be a 10 line block of code to essentially copy-and-paste into a new request and pass it along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this handler as a good start.  It currently works for POST requests only, but I'm looking to handle GET requests too.

If anyone reads this code and sees some way of making it simpler, go ahead and suggest the change.  This was a first attempt that worked for one of my situations.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="APICaller" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class APICaller : Implements IHttpHandler

Private _DestinationEndpoint As String = ""

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    If context.Request("endpoint") <> "" And (context.Request("debug") = "" Or context.Request("debug") = "false") Then
        Try
            _DestinationEndpoint = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(context.Request("endpoint")).ToString
            If (_DestinationEndpoint.IndexOf("http://") = -1) Then
                _DestinationEndpoint = "http://" & _DestinationEndpoint
            End If

            Dim newRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(_DestinationEndpoint)
            newRequest.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType
            newRequest.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod

            For Each hdr As String In context.Request.Headers
                Select Case hdr
                    Case "Content-Length", "Content-Type", "Expect", "Host", "Connection", "Accept", "User-Agent"
                    Case Else
                        newRequest.Headers.Add(hdr, context.Request.Headers(hdr))
                End Select
            Next

            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms)
            Dim data As Byte() = ms.ToArray()

            'If context.Request.RequestType = "POST" Then
            Dim reqStream = newRequest.GetRequestStream()
            reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            reqStream.Close()
            'End If

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(newRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

            Dim responseFromServer As String = "API Error"
            Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
            Dim responseStream As Stream = Nothing

            responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)

            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            Dim buffer As Char() = New Char(1024 * 8 - 1) {}
            Dim read As Integer = 0
            Do
                read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                sb.Append(New [String](buffer, 0, read))
            Loop While Not reader.EndOfStream

            If reader.EndOfStream Then
                responseFromServer = sb.ToString()
            End If

            response.Close()
            responseStream.Close()
            reader.Close()

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(responseFromServer)
        Catch ex As Exception
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h1>Welcome</h1>")
        If context.Request("debug") = True Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ul>")
            For Each hdr As String In context.Request.Headers
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<li>" & hdr & " - " & context.Request.Headers(hdr) & "</li>")
            Next
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<li>-- ContentType = " & HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType & "</li>")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</ul>")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```